# Scope not found on localhost

Tags: java, red5

I have created a server side application with a simple client side application.
Also I created the jarfile by compiling the source code of the server side and placed all the content in the Red5/webapp directory.

The problem I am facing is that when connecting the client side flash code to the server, the following two errors occur:

*Connection:Rejected*
*Connection:Closed*

When I check the log of the Red5 Server, it tells me:

*No Scope myapp found on localhost.*

The config files inside the WEB-INF directory:
(config files, server and client code, via pastie.org.)

[Config Files , Server Code , Client Code](http://pastie.org/4261492)

**sample** is the folder I placed in the Red5/webapp directory.

---

This has been my problem for three days.
I ask humbly for help here, since I cannot work things out myself, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your `red5-web.xml` file. Perhaps bean class names are not correct?

Comment: please you can check the config files and the server and the cleint code above , Please let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I'll do it later when I get a bit more free time.

Comment: if you just check the config files , it just take 5 min if you wanted to check them.

Comment: i have paste the code because i have checked many times , the class name is correct.